# Having two pointers/mice on the same computer

Tags: software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi Mouse & Keyboard for Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/multi-mouse-keyboard-for-mac)

Is is possible to have two pointers on the same computer? I was working on a project with a friend and it would've been really nice to have two pointers. Note that I am not asking how to connect two mice to a computer, I want *two* pointers on the same computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect multiple mice to share the same pointer.

Multiple pointers is a bit different, research and development is still ongoing in the Linux world that you may wish to peruse for information:

Video example of using multiple pointers:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2iYNfl-2Es

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Pointer_X

Here is, more of a demonstration site for OSX:

http://www.dualosx.com/dualosx_en.htm

Comment: Thanks! BTW, DualOSX...you can't actually download it. It comes in a .zip file and when you unzip it, it's a .txt file, so...