# problem with high sierra multiple users simultaneously

Tags: macos, screen-sharing

I'm trying to connect from windows to high sierra with another user on my mac that is working on it's own mac

I'm trying to make my mac to have two users to work with it at the same time.I have tried high sierra screen sharing but the problem is that when the first user(mac owner) is logged in to his account and I'm trying to connect to my own account on the mac by using VNC,The first user aromatically logout and both user start to use the same account.
But How can I make both user have their own account And use it simultaneously ?So each user can access his/her account at the same time?

I searched a lot and find out that lion Has this ability (per user share).Is it available for the mac ?Or any other solution to this problem ?
By the way ,the second user is from windows and is connecting through VNC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First item, you get two sessions max. If you are struggling with the first or second session, then the issue could be your VNC software that connects to the mac isn’t following Apple’s conventions to allow the second session to start. Since you didn’t specify versions of software you use on the connecting side, I’ll guess and give general advice.

There is no change I’ve needed on the mac that’s sharing the screen, just your client needs to be updated or you need a different client, but some people from [Windows report you need specific settings.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94666/how-to-use-mac-os-x-per-user-screen-sharing-from-a-windows-pc)

- Screens iOS app works to open a second session
- Screen Sharing app on the Mac (connect to server Finder menu - use vnc://whatever to connect) and Screens app on macOS all work with multiple sessions.

Apple Remote Desktop doesn’t open a second screen by default. It might have that option, but I only use it in the way you don’t - to share one session together.

Based on what os you are connecting from - these might help:

- [How to use Mac OS X "Per-user screen sharing" from a Windows PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94666/how-to-use-mac-os-x-per-user-screen-sharing-from-a-windows-pc)
- [Force screensharing to open new session](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285511/force-screensharing-to-open-new-session)
- [Are the changes to Lion's screen sharing documented anywhere publicly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19618/are-the-changes-to-lions-screen-sharing-documented-anywhere-publicly)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I've tried two vnc software. UtlraVnc and VNC Viewer. I'll try your reply and I'm tell the result .

Comment: I checked and the  trick is that the first user must be logged in and then the second user tries to log in.But there is a problem with that which if you need to log in again via VNC ,You have to log out from your account first .Is there any alternative To make that happen.I searched and there was a vine VNC but it's not running on High sierra.

Comment: I am not sure @Hamid - I run dozens of Mac mini and Mac Pro in data centers headless or with hdmi dongles that emulate a display but don’t have any cable. I’ve never had to log out of any accounts to get the first or second session running. I also never needed to add third party VNC server software on the Mac, the built in option works for our needs.